# Segmentation fault after fprintf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, fclose

I'm coding an algorithm in C, but I fall in SEGFAULT. This happens when, in a function, I open a file with append permission, I write something and then I close the file. The segmentation fault happens at `fclose` line. Here is an example.

```
FILE *fout;    
if((fout = fopen("pippo.txt","a"))!=NULL){
    fprintf(fout,"ciao\n"); 

    fclose(fout);
};
```

- The file `pippo.txt` exists
  *The `fout` pointer is not NULL
- If I try to just open and close the file (without `fprintf`) I don't have the segmentation fault
- If I use the "w" permission instead of append one I don't have the sigfault and it writes correctly the string in the file.

The cpu window when segfault happens indicates an error at SetfilePointer function as follows:

```
SetFilePointer()
msvcrt!_lseeki64()
msvcrt!_write()
msvcrt!_write()
msvcrt!_flsbuf()
msvcrt!clearerr_s()
msvcrt!fclose()
```

in particoular at `SetfilePointer()` the cpu window is:

```
0x00007ffae3468259 <+265>:  movl   $0x5,0x20(%rsp)
```

I don't understand  how to solve this error. Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Could you you post a [MCVE]

Comment: Do you experience this behavior in a main with only this code in it?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong in the code you posted. The problem may be elsewhere, where something gets messed up (e.g. buffer overflow/underflow or any other undefined behaviour). You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I have a function in the main, that I call. In this function I perform these operations. If i do the same directly in the main I don't have segfault

Comment: @user13431541 so you understand why with the posted code it is impossible to provide an answer. If the crash occurs in a given main+functionCall couple, that couple of informations need to be included in the provided code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't stream anything else in that function except for an input file opened to read and correctely closed.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni yeah I know because is just a small part of my program. For me it's very hard to post a reproducible code, because the are a lot of dependeces and I should post it complete, but I can't. Can you give me any advice on how those function in cpu window fail and what is the meaning of :
0x00007ffae3468259 <+265>:  movl   $0x5,0x20(%rsp)

Comment: @Jloc Then I'm afraid we can't help. As I write before, the problem is somewhere else. Read about "undefined behaviour".

Comment: You need to add a [mre] of a program that correctly compiles and reproduces the same problem, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.